# Does Amplify's JavaScript library retry on lost acknowledgement?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I'm wondering what, if any, built-in automatic retry logic exists in AWS Amplify's JavaScript front-end library for connection related errors. Actually it would be good to know about retry logic for all error types, but I'm mainly concerned with knowing how Amplify behaves when an acknowledgement is lost.

If a request is successfully received by a server and is carried out, but the response is lost for whatever reason, does Amplify automatically repeat the request because it doesn't know for sure whether the server received it? I need to know this as I build my backend and front-end logic going forward.

I assume whatever the answer is it's the same for all requests, whether they be APIGateway requests, AppSync, Cognito or even S3, but maybe I'm wrong?

I haven't found this information in Amazon's documentation anywhere so far, of course I could have missed it, but so far I'm unable to find it. If anyone knows the answer, please do point me to where in the documentation it's explained, if anywhere. Thanks!